# Increase font of rank and file labels in babaschess

Tags: babaschess

I'm trying to memorize the squares A-H 1-8, but its difficult when the labels are very tiny.  How can I increase the font-size of the Rank and File labels in babaschess.

Comment: Why do you need to specifically memorize the squares? Go through a book of good games in algebraic notation with a physical board and you'll learn some chess and become fluent in the notation for free.

Comment: Just trying to sharpen the saw.  In fact, memorizing the squares is part of increasing my literacy to make reading books more effortless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

Babaschess > File > Preferences > Board > Board Window > Board window display options > Show Coordinates > Font Size

Oh by the way, LiChess.org has a really neat feature to practise board square memorization in its training check it out!

Comment: Lichess coordinate training is really cool.  Thanks.